# Is there a way to change font color of portion of a string in VBA userform's label?

Tags: vba, formatting, label, userform

I'm trying to change the color of a portion of a string that is loaded into userform's label based on certain conditions. My attempt is to find the starting character and length of the string I want to format by using `instr` function and then loop through individual characters and change their `.forecolor` property.

```
startpoint = InStr(showformula, ListBoxValue)
endpoint = startpoint + Len(ListBoxValue)

For i = startpoint To endpoint
  LabelMain.Characters(i).ForeColor = RGB(255, 0, 0)
Next i
```

Unfortunately, I am getting error on the `LabelMain.Characters(i).ForeColor = RGB(255, 0, 0)` as it looks like I cannot select individual characters in VBA's label userform.

Is there another way to change the font color of only portion of the label's caption?

Thank you!

Comment: No. ForeColor applies to the label as a whole, not individual letters.

Answer (score 1):

Nope. If it's just a one off can just split your text into multiple labels and sit them on top of each other.

If your wanting something programmtic it would be a lot trickier, only solution I can think of would be to :

- Create array of the widths of all characeters in your font set.
- Calculate distance from edge of label where highlight text starts
- Replace text with spaces equal to highlight text lenght
- Create a new label over the top in correct position based on new distance.

  ```
   set Lbl = MyForm.Contorls.Add("Forms.Label.1", "MyNewLabelName",true)
   'Set properties of the lbl
  ```